# Findbug Invalid syntax for regular expression

Tags: java, regex

Before integrating findbug my application was running perfectly. After integrating findbug it prompt for the Invalid syntax for regular expression.
In my java application, following 3 occurrence giving error now

```
private final Pattern REG = Pattern.compile("^.+?\\s+(?<path>.+?)\\s+(udf|nfs|vboxsf|vmhgfs)\\s+");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?<name>\\w+?)-\\d+\\.\\d+");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?<url>https?://.+?),(.*),(?<date>.+?),(?<count>.+?),(.*?),(?<browser>.+?),(?<user>.+?)$");
```

What is the wrong with the above statement?

Comment: Could it be that findBugs is not yet able to parse Java 7 regex named groups? **edit** which findBugs version are you using?

Comment: There's a rejected bug [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/bugs/1262/) about named groups - unfortunately user submitted a bad `Pattern`... but in essence I *think* there might still be a bug...